# C++: Implementing Row Iterator for Table

Tags: c++, memory-management, iterator

I have a generic table class implemented in C++ that uses a `shared_ptr< ptr_vector< vector<T> > >` as its backing, where `T` is an arbitrary typename; the `ptr_vector` contains pointers to the vectors corresponding to the columns in the table. I decided to wrap the `ptr_vector` in a `shared_ptr` since the tables may contain many millions of rows, and the `vector`s containing data for each column in a `ptr_vector` for the same reason. (Please tell me if this can be improved.)

Implementing column-wise operations on this table is trivial, since I have access to the native iterator supplied by the vector. However, I also need the table to support row-wise operations: relatively mundane operations such as adding and removing rows should be supported, as well as the ability to use the STL algorithms with the table. Now, I have run across some design issues that I need some help to address:

1. It seems that implementing a custom iterator to conduct row-wise operations is necessary to accomplish what is describe above. Would boost::iterator_adaptor be the right way to go about doing this?
2. When the user adds rows to the table, I do not wish to impose a specific data structure upon the user -- how would I go about doing this? I am thinking of accepting iterators as parameters to the `add_row()` method.
3. If you think that I should be implementing this table structure differently, I am open to any suggestions that you may have for me. It was originally designed with the intent to store strings read from tab-delimited files containing hundreds of thousands of row entries.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Is the size of the table fixed or do you need insertion and erase operations in both dimensions?

Comment: The table should be able to shrink or expand in both dimensions.

Comment: Yikes. I almost wonder if it'd be most efficient to use a single `vector<T>` as the underlying container and just implement the relevant strided operations thorough two sets of custom iterators, row and column.

Comment: How would this be possible with a single `vector<T>` as the underlying container? I could perhaps use a `vector< vector<T> >,' but that's essentially what I'm doing now.

Comment: Perhaps you would find [Boost.multi_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html) useful.

Comment: @vp: You would use a single vector with M x N elements, access with strides, and `std::move` on insert/erase, I suppose. Just like a 1-D vector, only with more loops.

Comment: Oh, sounds neat -- let me take a look.

Comment: It would seem that deleting either a row or a column (whichever involves deleting non-contiguous elements) would incur more overhead than it would for the vector< vector<T> > approach, though.

Comment: @vp: It depends whether you want any sort of contiguous-memory guarantees or not. Sure, a vector of vectors would not have to move things around if you manipulate the correct dimension, but on the other hand if you had to insert something into the expensive dimension, you'd have to make many reallocations, whereas with the single vector you'd only allocate memory once for the entire thing (though you'd still be moving data around)... I'd just think the single vector is more symmetric and clean, but you'd have to profile (and think about your layout requirements).

Comment: @Kerrek Your suggestion to use Boost.MultiArray was very useful; it meets all of my requirements. Care to submit your suggestion as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Boost library has a container called [multi_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html) which provides and n-dimensional dynamic array which can be accessed and manipulated along each dimension. This seems to be very similar to what you are trying to build, perhaps you could use it instead?